# Repeated import path patterns in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any alternative to prevent typing repeated long paths while importing modules in python.

Current code:

```
from a.b.c.d.e.f.g import g1
from a.b.c.d.e.f.g import g2
from a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h import h1
from a.b.c.d.e.f.g.i import i1
```

I tried following code:

```
ref_path = a.b.c.d.e.f.g
from ref_path import g1
from ref_path import g2
from ref_path.h import h1
from ref_path.i import i1
```

But unfortunately it did not work. I cannot do from `a.b.c.d.e.f.g import *` since there might be too many modules within the `ref_path`.

If I am able to do this, I could easily maintain different common `ref_paths` used in different modules from one common location with minimal efforts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to use `importlib` as follows:

```
import importlib
ref_path = 'a.b.c.d.e.f.g'

g1 = importlib.import_module(ref_path).g1
h1 = importlib.import_module(ref_path).h.h1
```

**Edit**: Another way of doing it could be to import the ref path as a package and then assigning the sub-modules to local variables as follows:

```
import a.b.c.d.e.f as ref

g1 = ref.g1
h1 = ref.h.h1
```

Comment: Also, `importlib.import_module(ref_path).h.h1` will crash if `h` hasn't been imported yet.

Comment: From a readability point of view it is an improvement. OP surely knows how to import multiple submodules from a parent module by separating them with commas. The main point was to avoid writing the full path every time, not to do it in less lines...

Comment: Will it still be more readable after you fix that bug that throws an AttributeError in `importlib.import_module(ref_path).h`, though?

Comment: I can't see that bug in my system... MCVE: `import importlib`; `ref_path = 'numpy'`; `rand = importlib.import_module(ref_path).random.rand`; `rand()`. Works just fine.

Comment: That's because numpy imports the `random` submodule automatically. Try `importlib.import_module('urllib').request`.

Comment: I have tried this in my PyCharm Python 3.6 interactive shell and works fine too. Outside the IDE I do get the Attribute Error.

Answer (score 8):

There is no miracle cure for this problem.

There are, however, a few strategies you can use to make your imports a little bit nicer:

- **Import all names from a module at the same time**

  Instead of

  ```
  from a.b.c.d.e.f.g import g1
  from a.b.c.d.e.f.g import g2
  ```

  use

  ```
  from a.b.c.d.e.f.g import g1, g2
  ```
- **Use relative imports (if you're importing within your own package)**

  Assuming that this import is happening in `a.b.c.d.e`, you can replace

  ```
  from a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h import h1
  ```

  with

  ```
  from .f.g.h import h1
  ```

  This also works if you're in a sibling (sub-)module. For example, if this import is taking place in `a.b.c.d.e.x.y`, you can use

  ```
  from ...f.g.h import h1
  ```

  For more details about relative imports, see

  - [Intra-package references](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)
  - [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)
  - [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)
- **Refactor your package (if it's your own code)**

  If your package has more than 4 levels of submodules (like `a.b.c.d.e`), there's a pretty high chance that you should rethink your package structure. At that point you're really just shooting yourself in the foot. Perhaps `c` could be a standalone package, outside of `a`. Or perhaps `e` doesn't really need to be inside `d` and can be moved up a level or two. To quote the Zen of Python: Flat is better than nested.

### Critique of other suggestions

- **`importlib.import_module`**

  Someone suggested this:

  ```
  import importlib
  ref_path = 'a.b.c.d.e.f.g'

  g1 = importlib.import_module(ref_path).g1
  h1 = importlib.import_module(ref_path).h.h1
  ```

  This serves absolutely no purpose. Now you have to write `importlib.import_module(ref_path)` instead of `from a.b.c.d.e.f import`. It's not shorter. It's not more readable. It's nothing but a more verbose version of the next suggestion. (Read on...)
- **Assigning `a.b.c.d.e.f` to a variable**

  The next suggestion was this:

  ```
  import a.b.c.d.e.f.g as ref

  g1 = ref.g1
  h1 = ref.h.h1
  ```

  This looks nice, but it doesn't always work. If the `g` module doesn't automatically import the `h` submodule, this code will throw an AttributeError. To demonstrate:

  ```
  >>> import urllib as ref
  >>> urlopen = ref.request.urlopen
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'
  >>>
  >>> from urllib.request import urlopen  # this works, though
  >>>
  ```

  If this is inside your own package, there's an additional disadvantage to this solution: Your IDE most likely won't understand your imports, and won't automatically update them for you if you ever refactor your package structure. In the long run, old-fashioned `import` statements are more maintainable.